# Scheduling interval/cron job in a multi worker environment

Tags: cron, multiprocessing, backend, apscheduler

I built a simple web app using flask that execute cron jobs, using [APScheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), to be specific. However, when I pack the code with WSGI (uWSGI, gunicorn...), I've noticed that since WSGI tends to fork the application into multiple processes, it won't behave the same way as it is in deveopment environment (Running same job multiple times, doesn't run job at all...).

After some time-consuming research, reading throgh [docs](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-share-a-single-job-store-among-one-or-more-worker-processes), I came up with some solution:

1. Running a standalone process that packs the scheduler feature with some remote access mechanism (e.g. RPyC), and have the flask processes talk to this process for any actions related to scheduling.
2. Forget about the Scheduler, just take advantage of the cron command provided by the OS
3. Upon the start of WSGI Server, one of the worker process will be responsible to run the scheduler. If any other process has the nedd to access scheduler, talk to the process that runs the server. (This is a conceptional thought, I'm not sure if this is possible, either :(

So my question is: How is this so complicated?

Regardless of the programming language, operating system, deployment stack,...etc, I'm pretty sure I'm not the few people who has the need to run cron jobs along with web app. However, none of solutions above seems satisfying enough for me, actually.

Since this is my first time of building a web app, so I am wondering how did other programming lanuages, framework, or stacks solve this problem, or is scheduling job just isn't come in the scope of an app and should be take care of in some places else.

P.s. 
In my mind, a scheduler is supposed to be...

1. OS-independent, doesn't depent on OS-provided interface/feature, so that app is portable, i.e., can be runs on any stack.
2. Simple Stacking, no additional command to install/start/stop, runs when app start, off when app is stoped.
3. Bind/Handled within the app. Further conecpt of 2., app is responsible for hadling any mis-fired jobs if there's any downtime. (since last time I checked, none of the OS has provided such kind of feature)

Comment: Since you're not asking the solution to a programming question but you have an issue with the architecture of APScheduler, I would recommend that you ask this question on either the APScheduler Google group or Gitter. I'll be happy to answer you there. StackOverflow is the wrong venue for such a discussion.

Comment: @AlexGrönholm I'm not quite sure if APScheduler has adequate ability to achieve my goal (based on my knowledge to Operating System), but I appriciate your recommendation, I've dropped message there.

Comment: Running jobs at specific times is not something that a web application should be concerned with, in my opinion. The job of your Flask application is to deal with web requests. My opinion is that you should write your scheduled commands in a platform-independent way, but you should use operating system services to schedule the job to run at the correct time(s). Also, you talk about the web application as if it was a single item. In most cases a web application is composed of a lot of moving parts.

Comment: @Miguel Thanks for the suggestion, maybe I'll think more about the structure design.